# How to assign the same IP address for every computer connected ad hoc?

Tags: networking, windows-10, dhcp, static-ip

I have an interactive system with a computer running Windows 10 in the center. There is no wireless network, only one ethernet cable. There is an application running on this machine that sends data to let's say 192.168.10.100. There can be many different computers connected to the central computer, but only one at a time.

After pluging in, the computer should receive an IP address (192.168.10.100) and netmask and immediately start receiving data with as little configuration on their side as possible (static ip is not a solution - let's assume all of them have dhcp turned on).

I've tried to find a dhcp server which assigns ip (in this case only one) to every computer connecting to the central computer, but didn't successed with any.

Is there any solution to this for Windows?

Comment: Why would you want every computer to have the same IP? That would cause conflicts on your network

Comment: I have only one ethernet cable for an ad hoc connection. It's a completely closed system, no router, no network. Only one computer connected to another via ethernet.

Comment: @BigChris I'll do that if I won't find a software solution. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment about "no router" etc. Look for a softwasre DHCP server that you can install on your Windows 10 machine and create a DHCP pool of only one address - 192.168.10.100. A quick search  http://www.dhcpserver.de/cms/faq/which_server_os/ - it says it's been tested on Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit but that doesn't mean to say it will ONLy work on that platform...

Comment: You can setup DHCP reservations in most DHCP server but the problem is going to be that your computers wont know how to talk to each other, an IP address is a "unique" identifier and if all the computers have the same IP address you'll run into intermittent connection issues

Comment: Like @BigChris said, you'll want a pool of only one address that can be given out. The issue is you can't give it out if it's already being used/reserved by another machine's MAC address. To remedy that issue you'll need very short lease times or you'll have to manually expire the lease when you disconnect a machine so that it's available again when another machine connects.

Comment: You could use `Task Scheduler` to create a scheduled task to run on the event of `Network cable unplugged` (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392962(v=ws.10).aspx) to run a script to remove any leases from the DHCP server so that it "forgets" any clients and they get given a new IP (in our case they'll only ever get the one IP we want).